# Select All Items from Column

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbdatareader

I want to be able to get all the names in a specific column (contacts) within my access database and separate the unique names by utilizing a ";". Below is what i have but i keep only getting one results. Once i get all the results ill use the string to place into an email To section. Any help would be great!

```
con.Open();

String str3 = "Select contacts from table";
cmd3 = new OleDbCommand(str3, con);
dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

if (dr3.Read())
{

   results= dr3.GetString(12);
   ResultsFinal= lp.Replace("Open;", string.Empty)
                     .Replace("Open", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Replace if (dr3.Read()) by while (dr3.Read())

Answer (score 0):

You should create a loop for reading data from datareader, like this:

```
while (dr3.Read())
                {
results= dr3.GetString(12);
                   ResultsFinal= lpDirector.Replace("Open;", string.Empty)
                                     .Replace("Open", string.Empty);
}
```